# Where is the socket.io client library?

Tags: node.js, client, socket.io

As far as I have seen, there is no explanation as to where we are to locate the client side script for `socket.io` if `node.js` is not used as the web server. I've found a whole directory of client side files, but I need them in a combined version (like it's served when using node.js webs servers). Any ideas?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

socket.io.js is what you're going to put into your client-side html. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io.js"></script>
```

my script is located:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js
```

copy that file to where you want your server to serve it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Couldn't figure out where in that mess of directory structure that file was :)

Comment: Yeah, it's not that logical. A lot of people using socket.io ask that. All the best :-)

Comment: Thanks man! It's weird that there's no information about that in the docs or samples.

Comment: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client


<script src="http://<uri:port>/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: Please do not do that, use below solution

Comment: @dVaffection This does only work if the web app and socket.io are on the same server and port.

Answer (score 172):

The best way I have found to do this is to use [bower](http://bower.io/).

```
bower install socket.io-client --save
```

and include the following in your app's HTML:

```
<script src="/bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
```

That way you can treat the socket.io part of your client the same way you treat any other managed package.

Comment: This is the best solution, thanks!  In case this helps anyone else, the minified socket.io client is located in `bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js`

Comment: bower ftw. <script src="bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: Running "bowerInstall:target" (bowerInstall) task

socket.io-client was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "client/bower_components/socket.io-client" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.

Comment: This installed the library nicely, but it's missing a bower.json as far as I can tell. My gulp step that auto-concatenates bower libraries ('main-bower-files') doesn't pull it in.

Comment: I checked `bower info socket.io-client`, and it looks like it was registered to bower without a bower.json (so a default was created in the bower repo). You could either fork the project, create a bower.json, and register your own bower version. Create a pull request containing a bower.json. Create an issue and see if a contributor can create it.

Comment: Great work boys. Up and running in just seconds with this answer.

Comment: Geez, that `-client` was everything for me. I was just doing `bower install socket.io --save`.

Comment: `bower install socket.io-client --save` Why Bower require credentials to my GitHub account to download socketio client? I can install other packages no problem, but this one needs my password for GitHub...

Answer (score 25):

I think that better and proper way is to load it from this url

```
src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"
```

on the domain where socket.io runs. What is positive on this solution is that if you update your socket.io npm module, your client file gets updated too and you don't have to copy it every time manually.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. It is the recommended usage of the client-side include from Socket.IO documentation. It just explains where it comes from, along with the advantages @Capaj mentioned.

Comment: This is only the best solution IF Node.js serves the website where you want the connection to happen. That's a really big 'IF'.

Answer (score 8):

I used bower as suggested in Matt Way's answer, and that worked great, but then the library itself didn't have its own `bower.json` file.

This meant that the `bower-main-files` Gulp plugin that I'm using to find my dependencies' JS files did not pull in socket.io, and I was getting an error on page load. Adding an override to my project's `bower.json` worked around the issue.

First install the library with bower:

```
bower install socket.io-client --save
```

Then add the override to your project's bower.json:

```
"overrides": {
  "socket.io-client": {
    "main": ["socket.io.js"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For everyone who runs wiredep and gets the "socket.io-client was not injected in your file." error:

Modify your wiredep task like this:

```
wiredep: {
  ..
  main: {
    ..
    overrides: {
      'socket.io-client': {
        main: 'socket.io.js'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @k-d This solved it, but why is that? what doesn't happen by default with `socket.io-client`?

Comment: Because they do not want to support bower.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bower.json, add the socket.io-client dependency.

```
"socket.io-client": "0.9.x"
```

Then run *bower install* to download socket.io-client.

Then add the script tag in your HTML.

```
<script src="bower_components/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a bower compatible socket.io-client that can be install like this :

```
bower install sio-client --save
```

or for development usage :

```html
bower install sio-client --save-dev
```

link to [repo](https://github.com/shSina/socket.io-client)

Comment: Will you release any updates? socketio is on 1.3.5 now. Yours is very slow and clunky for some reason.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to automate the update of the bower client version ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io
make sure to have your index.html like this:

```
<!-- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/socketio/socket.io-client/master/socket.io.js -->
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>

<!-- build:js({client,node_modules}) app/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- ...... -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   angular.module('myapp', [
// ...    
'btford.socket-io'
]);

// do your angular/socket stuff
</script>
```