# How can I serve the socket.io client JavaScript along with my other JS libraries

Tags: socket.io, client-side

I understand that the socket.io JavaScript client file will be served from the Node.js server, but this is not good because I've used some sort of JavaScript library dependency manager like `require.js` or `steal.js`.

I wish I could serve the socket.io client JavaScript file from my main (static assets) server, not from Node.js server. Is this doable? And how can I achieve this?

Comment: I've also noticed socket.io may use Flash, so there are some swf files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is already useable from a client, and although on the server-side it's usually used with node.js, there is no reason you can't use it from another Javascript library. It has no node.js dependencies I'm aware of.

Comment: I can use it, but I need to get the source and build with other packages. And I'm not sure how to do it to make it right because of the awful files.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client)** is how you server socket.io to client.
As far as I know you cannot serve socket.io like node does to the client from outside node server.
Please do correct me if i'm wrong

Hope this helps

Comment: However, the documentation @DhirajBodicherla refers to also states: »If you choose to serve the client through other means, you can clone the socket.io-client repository and look at the dist/ subdirectory.» So it is possible, but requires some extra effort.

Comment: The Socket.io client library is also included with the Node.js package, as mentioned at [Where is the socket.io client library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528681/where-is-the-socket-io-client-library). Or, you can clone it from [GitHub](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to include the `socket.io` client JavaScript library from [CDNJS](http://cdnjs.com/):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.10/socket.io.min.js"><script>
```